# Issue when creating zip file from directory

Tags: r, zip

I have trouble with creating zip file from R. The same code worked perfectly at work with R version 3.4.2, 32 bit computer.

Now I am trying to run the same thing on R version 3.5.1, 64 bit computer, and the zip() command does not seem to work. What is going on?

```
zip(zipfile = "test.zip",files=list.files(getwd())) 
#create zip from whole directory, on 1st machine it works, now nothing happens
```

I checked the source code for zip() and when I debug it, I found out that system2 command does nothing.

```
  zip <- function (zipfile, files, flags = "-r9X", extras = "", zip = Sys.getenv("R_ZIPCMD", 
                                                                                  "zip")) 
  {
    if (missing(flags) && (!is.character(files) || !length(files))) 
      stop("'files' must a character vector specifying one or more filepaths")
    args <- c(flags, shQuote(path.expand(zipfile)), shQuote(files), 
              extras)
    if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") 
      invisible(system2(zip, args))
    else invisible(system2(zip, args))
  }

# I run this manually when trying to debug, nothing happens;
system2(zip, args) ## zip is a parameter here, not a function
####
Browse[2]> zip
[1] "zip"
Browse[2]> args
[1] "-r9X"                    "\"bla.zip\""            
[3] "\"[Content_Types].xml\"" "\"_rels\""              
[5] "\"docProps\""            "\"xl\""                 
[7] ""
```

For example absurd call does not give an error.

```
system2("blablađ",2) ## does nothing but no error or warning either
```

I am stuck trying to understand how does system2() function works and what do I need to change to create a compressed folder.

Thanks

EDIT: After taking the account the help from comment, I got following error:

```
Browse[2]> system2(zip, args,stderr = T)
Error in system2(zip, args, stderr = T) : '"zip"' not found
```

SOLVED: After installing Rtools for version 3.5 it worked.

Comment: Did you want to print the error? Maybe use `system2("blablađ",2, stderr = TRUE)`. What is the actual problem you are having with `zip()`? Is it just that no file appears?

Comment: Yes, zip file does not appear.

Comment: I got following error, I ll edit post.

Comment: Do you get something when you do `Sys.which("zip")`?

Comment: I got like an empty string: zip and bellow "".

Comment: @JacobJacox Please add a "@" before a pseudo so that we get a notification. Regarding your problem, you need a zip program in the path.

Comment: Or for instance do `zip(zipfile="test.zip", files=list.files(getwd()), zip = "C:\Program Files\Rtools\bin\zip.exe")`, assuming this is a path to a zip program.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. It did not have Rtools installed. Actually, I did not know that I have to do it separately. Again, thanks @StéphaneLaurent.

Comment: @JacobJacox Look at the help of `?zip`. You can set the path in an environement variable.

Comment: @JacobJacox I converted my comment to an answer. Please consider to accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the `zip` help:

> zip(zipfile, files, flags = "-r9X", extras = "",
>       zip = Sys.getenv("R_ZIPCMD", "zip"))
>
> zip   A character string specifying the external command to be used.

As you can see, the `zip` function has an argument `zip` to specify the external command to be used. On my machine it is:

```
λ where zip
C:\Oracle\Ora11\BIN\zip.exe
C:\Program Files\Rtools\bin\zip.exe
```

The `zip` program is available in Rtools, but it is also available on any (Windows?) machine, usually.

To check whether `zip` is found by R, type:

```
> Sys.which("zip")
                              zip 
"C:\\Oracle\\Ora11\\bin\\zip.exe"
```

If you get `""`, that means `zip` is not in the path, and if it is neither in the environment variable `R_ZIPCMD`, you have to specify its path in the `zip` argument.

Comment: Thank you! This finally solved my problem! Is there a way to permanently change where the zip path on System? I'm afraid next time I have to use zip I will have forgotten about this and I will have to find this answer again to fiz it haha